# BSDライセンスを利用したアプリの著作権表示について

Tags: ios, ライセンス

BSDライセンス（BSD-3-Clause）のオープンソースをライブラリとして利用し、iOSのアプリを作成しています。
著作権表示や免責事項等記載しないといけないかと思うのですが、どのように記載すればよいかわかりません。
ご存じの方、もしくはご経験のある方いらっしゃらないでしょうか。

---

インターネットで調べてみましたが、以下のような理解度です。

１.ソースコードには必ず記載する
　→コピーライト

２.配布物（マニュアル等の資料）があれば、記載しないと著作権の侵害となる
　→コピーライトに加え、免責事項も必要（？）

上記2点は実施しておかなければならないかと思っているのですが、正しいでしょうか？
「団体名等を宣伝に利用してはいけない」との事が情報としてあるのですが、マニュアルに記載する事とは別と判断して良いのでしょうか？

※ご指摘すいません。マルチポストとなっております。
　申し訳ありませんでした。
https://teratail.com/questions/201996

Comment: マルチポスト　https://teratail.com/questions/201996

Answer (score 0, accepted):

直接的な解答ではないですが、弁護士さんがBSDライセンスについて書いているサイトがあります。
ご参考までに。
[ＢＳＤライセンスが適用されたソフトウェアを商用利用する場合の注意点を教えてください。またＭＩＴライセンスとの違いも教えてください。](http://www.homu.net/%EF%BD%82%EF%BD%93%EF%BD%84%E3%83%A9%E3%82%A4%E3%82%BB%E3%83%B3%E3%82%B9%E3%81%AE%E7%89%B9%E5%BE%B4%EF%BC%9A%E5%88%A9%E7%94%A8%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B%E9%9A%9B%E3%81%AE%E6%B3%A8%E6%84%8F%E7%82%B9/)

Comment: ありがとうございます。やはり、バイナリで配布する際には、配布物にコピーライト・条項・免責事項等は記載しないといけない感じですね。参考にさせていただきます。